# Expanding/changing my query to find more entries using (potentially) IFELSE

Tags: sql, oracle

My question will use this dataset as an example.  I have a query setup (I have changed variables to more generic variables for the sake of posting this on the internet so the query may not make perfect sense) that picks the most recent date for a given account.  So the query returns values with a reason_type of 1 with the most recent date.  This query has effective_date set to **is not null.**

```
account date    effective_date  value   reason_type
123456  4/20/2017   5/1/2017    5       1
123456  1/20/2017   2/1/2017    10      1
987654  2/5/2018    3/1/2018    15      1
987654  12/31/2017  2/1/2018    20      1
456789  4/27/2018   5/1/2018    50      1
456789  1/24/2018   2/1/2018    60      1
456123  4/25/2017   null        15      2
789123  5/1/2017    null        16      2
666888  2/1/2018    null        31      2
333222  1/1/2018    null        20      2
```

What I am looking to do now is to basically use that logic to only apply to reason_type

1. if there is an entry for it, otherwise have it default to `reason_type`
2. I think I should be using an `IFELSE`, but I'm admittedly not knowledgeable about how I would go about that.

Here is the code that I currently have to return the reason_type 1s most recent entry.

I hope my question is clear.

```
SELECT account, date, effective_date, value, reason_type
  from
  (
    SELECT account, date, effective_date, value, reason_type
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by account order by date desc) rn
      from mytable
      WHERE value is not null
      AND effective_date is not null
  ) 
WHERE rn =1
```

Comment: What is your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Sorry.  I want to see the most recent entries for 123456, 987654, and 456789 and then figure out if the effective date is on or before todays date.

 After that, I also want to return the values for 456123, 789123,666888, and 333222 without the effective_date comparison since the field is nul.

Comment: I write an answer wish can help you. if that isn't your expect result you can show us your expect result data,that really help  @Dan Manion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want something like this (do you really have a column named `date` by the way? That seems like a bad idea):

```
SELECT account, date, effective_date, value, reason_type
  FROM (
    SELECT account, date, effective_date, value, reason_type
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY account ORDER BY date DESC ) AS rn
      FROM mytable
     WHERE value IS NOT NULL
) WHERE rn = 1
    -- effective_date IS NULL or is on or before today's date
    AND ( effective_date IS NULL OR effective_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, the column isn't actually named date. I've changed all of the column names for the sake of example.

Appreciate the answer.  That is very useful.